# Is it a security risk to log or otherwise store OAuth tokens for debugging purposes?

Tags: security, oauth

I am building an OAuth integration with my site. I want to log the tokens I get so that I can troubleshoot any problems later on. Is it safe to persist these tokens in a database or in log files?

Comment: I would advise against it. Think about it: they are just as valuable as passwords in terms of giving people access to resources within your web site.

Comment: even if they expire?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that database or log file is only accessible by the application and the application developer/owner, then yes.